# Enabling and Disabling system keyboard for my app

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-events, morse-code

This is a morse code application which converts morse code to alphabets and alphabets to morse.To do this I created m own keyboard. To display and hide this keyboard and system keyboard,I've used a code that is not working correctly for me.

```
 package com.aswdc_morsecode.activity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.aswdc_morsecode.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean isAlphaMorse = true;

    private TextView tvConvert;
    private TextView tvResult;
    private Button btnToMorse;
    private Button btnToAlpha;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

//        Method for keyboard starts here

```
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_et_convert);
        MyKeyboard keyboard = (MyKeyboard) findViewById(R.id.keyboard1);
```

//      below lines are used for enabling and dissabling system keyboard

```
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);

        InputConnection ic = editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
        keyboard.setInputConnection(ic);
        keyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        tvConvert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_et_convert);
        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_tv_result);
        btnToMorse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_btn_toMorse);
```

//Rest of the code

```
        btnToMorse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isAlphaMorse = !isAlphaMorse;
                MyKeyboard keyboard = (MyKeyboard) findViewById(R.id.keyboard1);
                keyboard.setVisibility(isAlphaMorse?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (isAlphaMorse) {
                    String txtToConvert = tvConvert.getText().toString();
                    String convertedTxt = MorseCode.alphaToMorse(txtToConvert);
                    tvResult.setText(convertedTxt);
                } else {
                    String txtToConvert = tvConvert.getText().toString();
                    String convertedTxt = MorseCode.morseToAlpha(txtToConvert);
                    tvResult.setText(convertedTxt);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with that code? How it should work, and how it works instead?

Comment: When I click on button btnToMorse the method switches from isAlphaMorse to isMorseAlpha. Simultaneously the onscreen keyboard(System keyboard) should be un poped and the keyboard for morse code that i have meade should be shown. Again when the btnToMorse is clicked the method switches and the system keyboard pops up. This is what i am trying to impliment

Comment: Right now once the system keyboard gets disabled , i am not able to enable it again .